# Three.JS project - loaders don't load local models (with screenshot)

Tags: three.js, mesh, loader

Example projects don't load 3d models to the scene. Or load but don't display, idk.

I tried both - the examples from three.js archive that I downloaded, also my own projects with my own models.

So I simply open three.js-master folder, open the index page in the examples folder, go through the list of examples. All examples work except the loaders examples. I just go through all of them and not a single format works, not obj, not fbx. What's wrong with local stuff? Online examples work but if I copy code from there it doesn't work.

See example
[image: The same for all local models]

Can someone just open that freaking three.js master folder on your desktop and run any example locally? I mean an example with a mesh loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run through a local webserver or change your browsers local file security policy.

It is all outlined at the three.js wiki at... [Three.js, how to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally).